# Concordance des temps, choix entre subjonctif et futur

Tags: subjonctif, concordance-des-temps, futur

Pour rassurer son client, un avocat peut dire :

1. Je vais plaider pour qu'il n'aura rien;
2. ou "Je vais plaider pour qu'il n'ait rien";
3. ou "Je plaiderai pour qu'il n'ait rien";
4. ou "Je plaiderai pour qu'il n'aura rien".

Quelle est la formulation exacte parmi ces 4 : aucune, la 1, la 2, la 3 ou la 4 ou un mix ?

Answer (score 3):

*Pour que* est toujours utilisé avec le mode subjonctif. Il n'y a pas de subjonctif futur, on utilise alors le subjonctif présent.

Les 2 formulations correctes possibles sont donc:

> Je vais plaider pour qu'il n'ait rien
>
> Je plaiderai pour qu'il n'ait rien.